# Update file collection active storage

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest, rails-activestorage

I'm making a REST API using Rails and Active Storage for storing files.

I have no issues on creating files, but I'm not sure about how to update a file collection property from an http request.

What I've done so far:

```rb
class MyModel < ApplicationRecord
    ...
    has_many_attached :files
end
```

In the controller

```rb
  # POST /mymodels
  def create
    @mymodel = MyModel.new(params)
    @mymodel.save!
    # send response to client
  end

  # GET /mymodels/:id
  def show
    response = mymodel.as_json
    response['files'] = mymodel.files.map do |file|
      { id: file.id, filename: file.filename,
        url: rails_blob_url(file, disposition: 'attachment') }.as_json
    end
    render json: response, status: :ok
  end
```

The frontend uses the file information to show some data on the screen, but the files can be removed and attached once the model was created, so I have two different file sources:

- The existing files (attached on POST)
- The new files (attached in an edit screen)

I'm not really sure how to use the existing files' information to a PUT request to make both existing and new files to be attached to the entity I'm updating.

Any help will be appreciated :)

Thanks in advance!